# How many results were returned?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I'm performing a query on a worksheet. I want to update the row if it exists or insert it if it doesn't. How can you check if a result was returned or not?

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($this->currKey);
$query->setWorksheetId($this->currWkshtId);
$query->setSpreadsheetQuery('cid = ' . $data['cid']);
$listFeed = $this->gdClient->getListFeed($query);

// This does not work!
if(empty($listFeed)){
 echo 'No results found!';
}
```

Comment: duh...that does not help. I didn't ask how to see the contents of $listFeed, but rather how many results are returned for the query I perform.

Comment: duh the information would tell me what step (function(s)) you need to take next. debugging 101

Comment: actually no it does not, simply lists several protected properties of the $listFeed object. That was the first thing I tried...

Comment: how would I know what you tried? anyway you are clearly not interested in my help - bye.

Comment: check the manual what is the return type of the `getListFeed()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
if(empty($listFeed->entries)){
    echo 'No results found!';
}
```

As Dagon suggested (perhaps a bit tersely), including some var_dump output will be helpful if this doesn't work.